# Automated tests in one project run in a different directory

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nunit, automated-tests, specflow

I am running a set of tests for work that I inherited from the prior testing. Most of the tests run fine from the central `bin` directory. One project, however, always fails because the current binary location (as seen by checking the value at `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`) is showing up in temp directory like "TestResults\username_OPSNASJVJBX06 2016-02-18 11_40_06\Out\" off of the solution directory instead of in `bin`. I've tried recompiling. I've tried changing the project settings. I've tried modifying `TestSettings.testsettings` as per a handful of other people who've run into this issue. None of it is solving my problem. The most frustrating part is that this did work about two weeks ago, but I couldn't figure out what I'd done to fix it, and it later seemed to revert back to using this directory.

I have checked the project settings and not only are all of the test projects set to export to the `..\bin` folder, but this test project's files show up there correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the project was not set to use the TestSettings.testsettings. The path was absolute, not relative, so when I copied it to the test box, the link broke, quietly turning off use of TestSettings.testsettings.